# Closest pair of points (CLRS pg 1043): Running time of splitting a sorted array into two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, closest-points

In finding the closest pair of points in O(nlgn) time, the pseudocode for splitting a sorted list into two sorted lists (CLRS 3rd ed pg 1043) is said to run in O(n) time.

[image: algorithm from CLRS pg 1043]

However, this assumes that line 4 runs in constant time, which I find hard to believe (I'd assume it runs in O(lgn) time if it were stored as a binary tree, giving a total running time of O(nlgn).

Y is a sorted array, YL and YR are the two new sub-arrays. PL is a subset of Y in random order, and YL is the same subset, but in sorted order.

Where am I going wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: When adding an element of Y to PL, mark it as belonging to PL. (Just a guess, I don't know how PL is formed).

Comment: If PL is made like reasonably big hashmap/hashset, expected average time of lookup can be O(1), but worst case is another story...

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin We are actually dealing with worst case for the big O notation.

Comment: @n.m. PL (for the sake of this algorithm) can be assumed to be a subset of Y in a random order.

Comment: The question is not what it is, but what kind of process is used to form it. Is it formed by picking elements of Y in some order?

Comment: @n.m. PL is formed by first sorting the points using the x coordinate, and then taking the left half. For e.g. if set of points P (sorted by x coord) is [(1,2), 2,5), (3,4), (4,2), (5,1)] then PL is [(1,2), (2,5)] and Y is the set of points P sorted by the y coord.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity sake we're assuming the list is of integers and not strings or integers which can complicate things greatly here.

There are two calculations to consider here:

1. for loop: This runs for length of Y times, which I'm assuming is N here
2. the tricky part - comparison of Y[i] with PL(Note: the comparison of two numbers is constant if we consider them to be of word size). Now, accessing Y[i] is constant since we're dealing with Random Access Machines. However, to compare it with an array PL of length, say, k will take k time. If this k is very small and independent of the size of input array Y, this ideally would be constant.

To write it with greater precision would mean you consider the time taken for k comparisons (length of PL) and hence, the total time of this pseudo code would be O(Nk). But, if the assumptions that k is random and independent of N hold true, it really is O(N)

Comment: PL is dependent on N - you can assume k = N/2, but thats

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is supposed to work in the book, but thinking about the way the algorithm looks like, you can come up with the following idea:

- `Y[i]`, `X[i]`, `YL[i]`, `XL[i]`, `YR[i]` and `XR[i]` are integers, corresponding to the index of the `i`th-point (so you just have to store some global array which, given the index, returns the `x` or `y` coordinate).
- `PL[i]` is a boolean, `true` if the `i`-th point is in the left part, `false` otherwise.

At each recursion step, you can compute `PL[i]` using `y` coordinates (`O(n)` time). Then you separate the set of points in two sets "left" and "right" using the algorithm from the book, replacing the line `if Y[i] in PL` by `if PL[Y[i]]` (such access is `O(1)`, so in overall we get `O(n)`).

This has `O(n)` time complexity and uses `O(n)` memory.

Thus the closest pair problem is solved that way in `T(n) = O(n log n)`.

Comment: I agree that it has O(n log n) time, but the book claims it has O(n) time.

Comment: @max_max_mir: I meant `O(n log n)` in overall for the whole closest pair problem (this particular step in indeed `O(n)`).

Comment: can you provide an example of this? Let's say Y = [(3,1), (2,2), (4,3), (1,4), (6,5)] and is sorted by y coord. PL is [(1,4), (3,1)] and is sorted by x coord. If I look up the list PL for any point in Y, it takes me O(n) time. However, I think you're saying there's a way to do a reverse lookup of sorts to determine if a point is in PL or not, and that takes O(1) time - but I don't quite see how.

Comment: @max_max_mir: I changed a bit the definition of `Y` and `PL`. Let's say we have some global arrays `xof = [2, 3, 4, 1, 6]` and `yof = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]` (the points in any order). Then `Y = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]` is the array of **indices** (here 1-indexed) of the sorted array. `PL = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]` means for example that `(2, 2)`, `(1, 4)` and `(6, 5)` belong to the left part.